# when the snake touch the food, i know why the new food comes up but why the old food disappears?

Tags: python

```
#food.py

from turtle import Turtle
import random

class Food(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("square")
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_len= 0.5, stretch_wid= 0.5)
        self.color("navy")
        self.speed("fastest")
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        random_x = random.randint(-280, 280)
        random_y = random.randint(-280, 280)
        self.goto(random_x, random_y)

#main.py

is_on = True
while is_on:
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    snake.move()
    if snake.segment[0].distance(food) < 15:
        food.refresh()
```

when the snake(there is a snake which made of three turtles(square)) touch the food(distance < 15), i know why the new food comes up but why the old food disappears? there is not function that erase the old food

Comment: Needs author edit / A community-specific reason / Blatantly off-topic

Answer (score 2):

There is no "new food". You only have one food / one `Food` instance and *that* existing food changes location to a new random one.